# Azure CosmosDB (formerly DocumentDB) receiving lots of requests I'm not sending

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Last night I created a new Azure CosmosDB instance. I created a new database and collection and went home without writing any data to it.

This morning I went back to the Azure portal and found my brand-new, empty database racked up **11,820 requests** overnight! Where are these requests coming from?! Is this normal? Should I expect to see ~354,600 phantom requests each month even if I never use the database?

I'm not even sure what to search for on SO or Google. I tried things like 'Azure CosmosDB shows requests I didn't send', 'CosmosDB phantom requests', etc but didn't find anything related to this problem. Can anyone explain what's going on?

[image: Screenshot of Azure showing the 11.82K requests I didn't send!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently a bug that causes this chart to show unrelated internal service traffic. The fix is under way.

Sorry for any confusion it might have caused and please use Metrics tab for any usage information.

Comment: Thanks for the inside info! I was freaking out a little.

Comment: No worries, if you face any issue please write us to askcosmosdb@microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any active Cosmos DBs running now, but about four months ago I was using it and never saw anything like that.

Notice the color-key on the graph -- they're all `HTTP 403` which is "Forbidden". According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/http-status-codes-for-documentdb) these events result in a 403 response:

> The authorization token expired.
>
> 403 is also returned during a POST to create a resource when the resource quota has been reached. An example of this is when trying to add documents to a collection that has reached its provisioned storage.
>
> 403 can also be returned when a stored procedure, trigger, or UDF has been flagged for high resource usage and blocked from execution.

Microsoft being who they are, there are [other docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/http-status-codes) which also say this about a 403 response:

> Returned when you pass an invalid api-key.

Just a guess: The new service you created matches the name of a service someone previously created then deleted, and you're picking up zombie traffic from something that used to hit that service.

Their docs about [diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/logging#what-is-logged) don't list `HTTP 403` as logged traffic, but I'd probably go to the Activity tab on the portal and take a look anyway. (It does say `HTTP 401` "Unauthorized" are recorded, I wouldn't be surprised if it was just an oversight that 403 isn't mentioned.)

If that doesn't reveal anything useful, I'd open a ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the response. @matias-quaranta's answer indicates there's an issue with the traffic reporting instead of an issue with the traffic itself. There aren't any other CosmosDB instances in my organization. Are you saying the traffic could be from users in a different organization that happened to use the same database name?! Are database names meant to be globally unique across Azure?

Comment: I was just floating a wild guess, that perhaps the name you chose had been used (then deleted) by someone else in the past. Names are unique for as long as they exist, but if you delete the resource, that name becomes available again. Good info from Matias though, I'd have been worried too!